# How to detect a SQL Server database has been restored

Tags: sql-server, database, backup, restore

Is there anything unique to a SQL Server database instance which makes it possible to detect it has been restored. If a client is using a database and decides to restore and run another copy of the same database on a different server - is there a way to tell the difference between the two with a t-sql query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to identify a database as a restore/copy of another database:

- [`service_broker_guid`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178534.aspx) is usually the easiest way. It is generated when the database was created and is preserved during restore/attach operations. It can be changed explicitly using `ALTER DATABASE ... SET NEW_BROKER;` so different GUIDs do not necessarily imply different DBs. But identical GUIDs imply a common origin of the databases.
- [dbi_familyGUID](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/search-engine-qa-20-boot-pages-and-boot-page-corruption/) is an undocumented boot page field that is preserved on restore.
- the recovery path and [recovery fork LSNs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175078%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) are documented and can be used to identify a common origin, but they diverge fast and a database that was restored even recently will soon lose trace of a common origin with another db by simply using the fork LSNs.
- encrypted databases ([TDE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934049.aspx) can easily be identified through the page nonce (undocumented method, requires expert knowledge) as long as the encryption key is not changed (ie. no total re-encryption is not forced, losing all nonces).
- application layer methods can use code signing: generate a key pair, sign a dummy module, drop the private key. Since the signature can never be re-generated (private key was dropped forever) a copy of the database cannot hide its origin w/o dropping the signature, which is obviously [tamper evident](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamper-evident).

As you see there are several ways, varying in level of expertise required and in the degree of tampering evidence they provide. It boils down to your requirements and real use case. Ultimately, remember that SQL Server is **not** a DRM product. If you have some code/design which you believe is invaluable and must be protected then you should provide the application as a hosted service so that this perceived IP never leaves your physically controlled environment.

Answer (score 0):

Database developers and administrators often use GUIDs as primary keys for database tables to ensure uniqueness between databases. This material in about comparing GUIDs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254976.aspx